# Sending a POST from React to my localhost:8080 that is running on Spring Boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am having a problem with submitting my form that I created on React.JS and sending it to my REST API. I am currently getting a 500 error at the moment and can't figure out what I need to do to fix this problem.

Comment: How is the server receiving the request?

Comment: from axios I do a axios.post call the localhost and thats when the error occurs

Comment: I figured out the problem I was getting a null pointer exception because it wasn't reading my date and coming back null